# PHP cannot POST /email.php error

Tags: php, html, forms, wamp

I am creating a website with a contact form that sends an e-mail to me with information from the visiting user (name, email, subject and message). I have tried using both the `mail()` function as well as the PHPMailer library, but keep getting the error `Cannot POST /email.php` as soon as I submit the form.

I think it has something to do with my HTML code, but I am not entirely sure. I have attached both the HTML and PHP code below.

## HTML Code

```
<div class="col-md-9  wow fadeInRight animated">
                    <form class="contact-form" action="/email.php" method="post" >
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sender" id="sender" placeholder="Name">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="senderemail" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sendsubject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <textarea class="form-control" style="resize:none" name="sendermessage" id="message" rows="25" cols="20" placeholder="Type message here..."></textarea>
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default submit-btn form_submit" value="SEND MESSAGE"></input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

## PHP Code - Using `mail()` function

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $recipient='naman.mandhan@gmail.com';
    $subject=$_POST['sendersubject'];
    $sender=$_POST['sender'];
    $senderEmail=$_POST['senderemail'];
    $message=$_POST['sendermessage'];

    //$mailBody="Name: $sender\nEmail: $senderEmail\n\n$message";

    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderEmail>");

}
?>
```

## PHP Code - Using PHPMailer

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;

//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();

//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
// use
// $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
// if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6

//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 587;

//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = "naman.mandhan@gmail.com";

//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "nahdnam";

//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom($senderEmail, $sender);

//Set an alternative reply-to address
//$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');

//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress($recipient, 'Naman Mandhan');

//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = $subject;

//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
//$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));

//Include the sender message in the body
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->AltBody = $message;

//Attach an image file
//$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}

?>
```

## Things I Have Checked/Tried

1. email.php is in the same folder as the html file.
2. Configured php.ini to the Gmail SMTP server and port.
3. I receive the following error and have checked but there is nothing that should be causing it, since I have used the same WAMP local server on a different project and gotten the code to write data into a database through PHP.

   `[21-Jul-2016 23:52:23 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.`

   `in Unknown on line 0`

   `[21-Jul-2016 23:52:23 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.`

   `in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: Maybe it has nothing to do with email.  If you remove everything from the PHP file and just do `print_r($_POST)`, when you submit your form, are your variables echoed back?

Comment: @BeetleJuice It doesn't echo anything back. I feel like it's not even getting to the email.php page.

Comment: Yep, I suspected as much; that's why I said your problem may have nothing to do with email and asked you to run that test. It appears Your script is never executed. I suggest you open your browser's dev tools and watch what network connections are attempted when you submit the form. In particular, look for the url to `email.php` and check whether it's correct.

Comment: `mail()` required a mail server to be installed. Windows does not have an email server by default. Using `phpMailer` is a good option

Comment: @BeetleJuice Tried that it throws a 404 Not Found error at me. email.php is in the same folder as the html file. All of my links have `127.0.0.1:58785/_file_name.extension_` as their URLs in the window, so I tried editing my `action=` to include the IP address but that's navigating to a different page and opening a new blank page.

Comment: @NamanMandhan take a look at my solution. Comment below it to let me know whether it worked.

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in the code for your form / email.php

in the  form the input for subject is

```
name="sendsubject"
```

but in your email.php it is

```
$subject=$_POST['sendersubject'];
```

Given the other two php inputs are sender..., it would be easier to change the form input name to be:

```
name="sendersubject"
```

Incidentally - you should also include labels with a for="" attribute that links the label to the id of each input. This is for accessibility and SEO purposes to ensure that the label and input are linked.

Comment: Thank you for catching that! Unfortunately, fixing the typo didn't fix the error and neither did adding the `for` attribute. It seems like the form isn't even being submitted by the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

In your form, change the action parameter from

```
action="/email.php"
```

To:

```
action="email.php"
```

The problem was that the first path is relative to the root of the website, so the form is POSTing to `example.com/email.php` and not finding anything. You get a `404 Not found` result.

The 2nd path will look for `email.php` in the same folder as the HTML file.

Comment: Yep. That's what I originally had before I asked this question, but it gave me the same error. Is it potentially a file structure problem?